# Incorrect distance being produced by my catapult game

Tags: c++, formula, physics

I seem to be having a serious problem involving the distance equation in my catapult game. The equation is meant to calculate the distance of a projectile launched by a catapult with a given velocity and launching angle. Usually the distance is always ridiculously high.

The velocity is calculated by certain user input densities so there may be a problem with that as well. I disabled the angle validity check and set the firing angle to 90 (wouldn't this give me 0 distance) and I got pretty high number.

I am unable to verify what is causing the problem with the program because I don't take physics and I would know any errors in the equation (our teacher supplied us the formula). I was wondering whether any physics savvy programmer could help me fix this game?

P.S. I think the problem may be being caused by my radian conversions. Here's a snippet of my code:

```
          cout << "Choose a material to launch:" << endl
               << "1) BIRCH WOOD (670 kg/m^3)\n2) ICE (917 kg/m^3)\n3) FLAMING COAL (1500 kg/m^3)\n4) ASBESTOS (2450 kg/m^3)" << endl;
          cin  >> materialChoice;
          materialChoice = int(materialChoice);
          while (materialChoice < 1 || materialChoice > 4)
          {
                cout << "Please choose a valid material type:" << endl
                     << "1) BIRCH WOOD (670 kg/m^3)\n2) ICE (917 kg/m^3) 3) FLAMING COAL (1500 kg/m^3)\n4) ASBESTOS (2450 kg/m^3)" << endl;
                cin  >> materialChoice;
                materialChoice = int(materialChoice);
          }

          switch (materialChoice)
          {
          case 1:
               density = 670;
               break;
          case 2:
               density = 917;
               break;
          case 3:
               density = 1500;
               break;
          default: 
               density = 2450;
          }

          cout << "Now select a launch angle between 20 and 70 degrees:" << endl;
          cin  >> angleChoice;

          while (angleChoice < 20 || angleChoice > 70)
          {
              cout << "Please select a valid launch angle between 20 and 70 degrees:" << endl;
              cin  >> angleChoice;
          }    

          cout << "Now select the radius of the projectile between 6 cm and 10 cm:" << endl;
          cin  >> radius;
          while (radius < 6 || radius > 10)
          {
                cout << "Please select a valid radius for the projectile between 6 cm and 10 cm:" << endl;
                cin  >> radius;
          } 
          velocity = 360000.0/(density * radius);
          distance = 2 * sin(RADIAN * (angleChoice)) * velocity * cos(RADIAN * (angleChoice)) * velocity/9.8;

          cout << "The projectile goes flying! Press any number to check where it landed" << endl;
          cin  >> null;
          shortDiff = (abs(distance - 24));
```

Comment: Why `materialChoice = int(materialChoice)`? Is `materialChoice` not an `int`? Why not? And if it *is* and `int` then why the casting?

Comment: As for your problem, try to step through the code in a debugger, line by line, to see which of your calculations might be wrong.

Comment: What is the trajectory equation you are implementing? Yours doesn't look correct. And what is the value of the constant `RADIAN`? I don't understand why the velocity would be inversely proportional to radius: that equation is not even *dimensionally* correct!

Comment: The value of RADIAN is 180/PI and the exact trajectory equation our teacher wrote is: Distance = 2*sin(toRadians(launchAngle))*Velocity*cos(toRadians(launchAngle)*Velocity/9.8.

Comment: Also the the velocity equation she gave us is: Velocity = 360000/(projDensity*projRadius)

Comment: What is the expected output and what is the aactualone? Also, what are the bariable types? Are you dure, your formula for the velocity is correct? Is it possible, you are calculating your distance in cm?

Comment: You have to divide by RADIAN, not multiply

Comment: MikeMB Thanks so much I literally figured it out right before I checked your comment

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The value of `RADIAN` should be `PI/180`. 
(PI radian)/(180 degrees)*(ANGLE in degrees) will give you the result in RADIAN.
 Make the changes and then debug, if required.